# Passing values between fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am making an Android app in Kotlin (following MVVM as much as I can if it matters) and my app structure is as follows:

1 Activity (MainActivity) which contains a FrameLayout and a BottomNavigationView.

The FrameLayout is filled dynamically with Fragments per BottomNavigationView clicks. One Fragment then opens an another fragment on click. That latter fragment is structured as follows:

1 NavigationView (navigationQuestions) and 1 FrameLayout (frameQuestion)

The FrameLayout should change Fragments based on NavigationView clicks.

Those containing fragments contain a textview and a listview.
I have implemented all of the above without many issues.

The problems arise when I need to communicate backwards between the last child fragment and its parent fragment because I need to, based on the item in the listview that's been clicked, change the color of the navigationview text that opened that fragment and change the color of that listview entry. I have tried calling the parentFragment but I can't access it's variables, tried with bundles, but they always seem to be null etc.

Also, I can't seem to maintain the state the last fragment is in when I change to an another one with the navigationview.
I am changing fragments like this:

```
navigationQuestions.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
                val transaction = this.activity?.supportFragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
                val index : Int = it.title.toString().toInt()-1
                transaction.replace(R.id.frameQuestion, fragmentQuestions[index])
                transaction.commit()
                return@setNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
```

fragmentQuestions is a MutableList that I create on the start of the class and fill when I fill the navigationView. The reason I did this is because each time I pressed the navigationView, a new instance of that Fragment was created, which isn't really what I want, so this solves it.

I have tried saving the state of the fragment with various override combinations including onPause(), onInstanceSaved, onViewDestroyed() etc, but my Bundle always remains null.

So, the question is, is there an efficient way to, on listView click, color the navigationView entry that belongs to the parent fragment and keep the current fragment saved so that when I switch to an another navigationview fragment and back, it remains the way it was?

I am using onCreateView in all my Fragment classes and this is the listview onitemclicklistener:

```
answersList.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
        if(position == question.correct-1) {
                (view as TextView).setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.greenanswer, null))
            parent.isEnabled = false
        }
        else {
            (view as TextView).setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.redanswer, null))
            parent.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
```

I have tried accessing the navigationview with something like

```
              (parent.parent.parent.parent as ViewGroup).get(0)
```

But I quickly realized that I can't access it that way :(

The look of the navigationview and the framelayout is:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsugJ.png)

Any help & tips? I can provide more detailed code of any part necessary, didn't want to overwhelm the question with code which isn't needed as there is a lot of code.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragments

Answer (score 1):

you can pass data to the parent fragment by calling

```
 setFragmentResult(
                    REQUEST_KEY_FRAGMENT,
                    bundleOf(EXTRA_DATA to "but your data here")
   )
```

and on the parent activity u should listen to the result as following :

```
setFragmentResultListener(REQUEST_KEY_FRAGMENT) { key, bundle ->
            bundle.getString(EXTRA_DATA)?.let {

          
            }
        }
```

you should have this dependency in your project:

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-beta01"
```